# Cardinality of a set with specific conditions

Tags: combinatorics

Fix any positive integer $n$ and let $X=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

1. Find the cardinality of the set
   $$S=\{(a,b,c)\mid a,b,c\in X, a<b,a<c\}$$
2. Fix any positive integer $k<n$. In the set $S$ defined above, find the number of elements that additionally satisfy the constraint that
   $$a+b+c=k$$

---

#1 is fine, fix $a=1$ and see that $b,c$ both have $n-1$ choices. So extending this we see that $|S|=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(n-i)^2$.

My problem is entirely with #2. My first thought is that this is counting the number of integer partitions of $k$ into $3$ parts with smallest part $a$. This is not illuminating at all. I suspect there's a way to view this as counting integer solutions, but the constraints on $a,b,c$ are bogging me down.

Comment: I think if I view this as a "stars and bars" then I might get somewhere. I have $k-a$ balls to distribute into $2$ boxes.

Comment: Confirmed this is close, but wrong. Since $b>a$ and $c>a$. I think I can do $b-a+c-a=k-3a$.

Comment: Running stars and bars on this is not sufficient because the boxes (b-a) and (c-a) cannot have 0 objects in them. So distribute 1 to each, i.e. running stars and bars on $k-3a-2$. Hence, the answer is $\sum_a(k-3a-1)$.

Comment: Now to determine the valid $a$ based on $k$ and I'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that $a<b$ and $a<c$. Letting $d=b-a$ and $e=c-a$, this means $d$ and $e$ are positive integers. In terms of $a,d,e$, the equation $a+b+c=k$ becomes
$$
3a+d+e=k
$$
But now, there are no inequality restrictions among $a,d,e$. The only restrictions are that $a,d,e$ are positive integers.$^*$ Can you count solutions to this modified equation?

$^*$ Technically, we also have the restrictions $a\le n$ and $d=b-a\le n-1$ and $e\le n-1$, but since $k<n$, these do not come into play.